# How do I get the source path of a VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files, one being my template file with all the macros in it, and the other being the file I'm actually processing.

Since the filename of the processed file is not always the same, I activate the macro with the file being processed as the active workbook.

Is there any way to get the path of the other workbook, where the VBA macro is actually saved, even if other files are potentially opened?

Comment: The workbook containing the VBA code can be accessed via `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @Ike Well that was simple, and yet googling turned up nothing. Thanks!